Where to get Debian packages for Visual Studio Code from: packages.microsoft.com/repos/code or packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode?
To install Visial Studio Code on Debian, different sources advise using different repositories:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux advises to use https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code, whereas

https://wiki.debian.org/VisualStudioCode advises to use https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode .


Any difference as far as the latest version on amd64 is concerned? The latest versions in the two pools seem the same (code_1.89.1-1715060508_amd64.deb at the time these lines are written), though the directories https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/pool/main/c/code and https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/pool/main/c/code are different (as of now):

Any official rationale or any official reason for having two places? After all, Microsoft could offer only one with all the files.
PS. Visual Studio Code is NOT the same as Visual Studio.

As a general rule, it’s best to follow the instructions provided by the repository publisher, i.e. Microsoft in this case.
As you mention, the two directories have different contents; in addition, the code and vscode Package files are different, with the latter referencing more versions of the package. Both have the same latest package though so you’d get the same package from either repository. Other than that I don’t know what the difference is or even why there are two different repositories.
